# Why should $\arg\max_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert A x\Vert$ be a linear combination of the rows of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd, singular-values

From the singular value decomposition of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, we should have $\Vert A \Vert = \sigma_1$, where $\sigma_1$ is the top singular value of $A$.

This would mean that the maximum argument (unique up to sign?) of $\Vert A \Vert = \arg\max_{\Vert x \Vert = 1} \Vert A x \Vert$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$.

However, what is the intuition as to why $x$ must be a combination of the rows, and not anything more complex?  Is this even true?

Comment: Any $x$ with $\|x \| = 1$ can be written as $\alpha u + \sqrt{1 - \alpha^2} v$, where $u$ is a unit vector in the span of the rows of $A$, $v$ is a unit vector in its orthogonal complement, and $\alpha \in [0, 1]$. But the $v$ part does not contribute anything to the norm $\| A x \|^2$, which is why the maximizer should be contained in the row span of $A$.

Also, note that the maximum argument is not unique. It is only unique up to sign when the top singular value is strictly larger than the rest.

Comment: @VHarisop Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $x$ is a unit vector that is not a linear combination of the rows of $A$. We can then write $x = u + v$, where $u$ is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ and $v$ is orthogonal to the rows of $A$ (which is to say that $Av = 0$). Note that
$$
\|Ax\| = \|Au + Av\| = \|Au\|.
$$
In fact, if we just got rid of the $v$ component and scaled $u$ to be a unit vector
(note that $\|u\|^2 = 1 - \|v\|^2 < 1$), we'd end up with
$$
\left\|A \frac{u}{\|u\|}\right\| = \frac{\|Au\|}{\|u\|} > \|Au\| = \|Ax\|.
$$

Comment: Thanks, very logical, didn't think to do a projection to the row space.